# AJAX function not passing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to make that when timer ends I get "Not active" message instead of "Active". The timer and code seems to work until this `$('.clock').eq().countdown(inputDate)` after this code, the function not working, no console.log's showing when checking. The same function works on one object but when it comes to foreach loop it doesnt work. This is my html line which should replace:

`<td><span class="timeProduct label label-success"></span>`

This is my ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var inputDate = new Date($('#count').text());
    var timeProduct = $(".timeProduct");
    timeProduct.html('Aktyvus');
    inputDate.setDate(inputDate.getDate() + 7);
    $(".clock").countdown(inputDate, function(event) {
            $(this).text(
                event.strftime('%D dienos %Hh %Mmin %Ssek')
            );

            $('.clock').eq().countdown(inputDate)
                .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
                    var timeProduct = $(".timeProduct");
                    timeProduct.removeClass("label label-success");
                    timeProduct.addClass('label label-danger');
                    timeProduct.html("Pasibaigė");
                });

        });
});
```

**EDIT**

This is my HTML with foreach loop

```
@foreach($bids as $b)
<tr>
    <td><img style="height: 50px" src="{{$b->product->img_1}}">
        <strong><a href="/preke/{{$b->product->id}}/{{$b->product->slug}}">{{$b->product->title}}</a></strong>
    </td>
    <td>{{number_format($b->product->price, 2)}} EUR</td>
    <td>{{$b->created_at}}</td>
    <td><span id="count">{{$b->product->created_at}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="clock"></span></td> // This is where timer appears
    <td><a style="font-size: 11px" href="/unmark-auction/{{$b->id}}" class="unCheck btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Nebesekti</a></td>
    <td><span class="timeProduct label label-success"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**And this is updated AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var inputDate = new Date($('#count').text());
    var timeProduct = $(".timeProduct");
    timeProduct.html('Aktyvus');
    inputDate.setDate(inputDate.getDate() + 7);
    $(".clock").countdown(inputDate, function(event) {
        $(this).text(
            event.strftime('%D dienos %Hh %Mmin %Ssek')
        );
        var index = $(".clock").index(this);
        $('.clock').eq(index).countdown(inputDate)
            .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
                var timeProduct = $(".timeProduct");
                timeProduct.removeClass("label label-success");
                timeProduct.addClass('label label-danger');
                timeProduct.html("Pasibaigė");
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: `eq()` requires an argument, an index for the element you want to get. Calling `eq()` without any arguments doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Okay, now it works. But incorrectly. It shows the same timer on all products no matter what the date they were `created_at`

Comment: If you're trying to execute this countdown function inside a foreach you'll have to give current index to `eq()` as argument. Could you please provide your whole code with HTML and foreach loop?

Comment: @MarcBellêtre Sure, I've updated my question :))

Comment: Ok thanks but you should also provide the code of your countdown function and even write this in a Fiddle so we can test it live.
I think I found out what was wrong with your code so I gave you an answer but it would be better if we could check it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are only calling your countdown function on the first .clock element. You should call your countdown function inside a loop like this:

```
$('.clock').each(function(index, elt) {
    elt.countdown(inputDate).on('finish.countdown', function(event) { 
    var timeProduct = $(this).parent().find(".timeProduct");
    timeProduct.removeClass("label label-success");
    timeProduct.addClass('label label-danger');
    timeProduct.html("Pasibaigė");
  });
});
```

**UPDATE :**

First of all you have to use a class name instead of an id for each "clock" element in your table. Then you have to loop on each row of your table to apply countdown function on each clock element.
You also did not correctly use jQuery countdown function (which I guess is this one: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/). The "finish" event should be attached to the DOM element on which you previously attached a countdown function.

In your code you were attaching the same countdown function to every clock element, then you were attaching another countdown to the first clock element in the callback function which did not make any sense.

You should instead do something like this:

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
    var inputDate = new Date($(this).find('.count').text());
    var timeProduct = $(this).find('.timeProduct');
    timeProduct.html('Aktyvus');
    inputDate.setDate(inputDate.getDate() + 7);

    $(this).find('.clock').countdown(inputDate, function(event) {
      $(this).text(event.strftime('%D dienos %Hh %Mmin %Ssek'));
    }).on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
      var timeProduct = $(".timeProduct");
      timeProduct.removeClass("label label-success");
      timeProduct.addClass('label label-danger');
      timeProduct.html("Pasibaigė");
    });

  });
```

Here is the working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mo6fhum5/

Comment: Timer only shows in first object. But if I add `.eq()` before `each` then the timer is on all elements are like the first one.

Comment: Could you please provide a jsFiddle? I don't really get what is wrong and what you are trying to do so it would help !

Comment: I made a screen. In the first screen is the only result that I get with your code. And in the other screen is the result that I get when I write code like this: `$('.clock').eq().each(function(index, elt)` The ending dates `liko` should be different. http://imgur.com/a/RIkLg

Comment: Hey sorry for late response. Now I'm getting `NaN` on every number

Comment: Hey, what number are you talking about? Did you change your HTML? Please be more specific so I can understand what is going on

Comment: About date numbers. They're all `NaN` now. I don't changed my HTML

Comment: `NaN dienos NaNh NaNmin NaNsek`

Comment: MY BAD! I forget to change id to class. Now it's working! Thank you mate!!

Comment: In your HTML did you replace `<span id="count">` by `<span class="count">`? / Edit : great you're welcome ;)